# Merging two JavaScript plug-ins

Tags: javascript, datatables, tabledit

I've created a php page that displays a table of users from mysql database and has many functionalities; edit or deleting each row using tabledit plugin and showing/hiding selected columns, searching.. users using datatables plug-ins. The problem that I'm facing is that those two plug-ins doesn't seem to work in the same time, any suggestions?? Here's the JavaScript code that manages those functionalities:

```
<script >

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  
  var dataTable = $('#editable_table').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
      url:"fetch.php",
      type:"POST"
    }
  });
  
  $('#column_name').selectpicker();

  $('#column_name').change(function(){

    var all_column = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"];

    var remove_column = $('#column_name').val();

    var remaining_column = all_column.filter(function(obj) { return remove_column.indexOf(obj) == -1; });

    dataTable.columns(remove_column).visible(false);

    dataTable.columns(remaining_column).visible(true);

  });
}); 
</script>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#editable_table').Tabledit({
      url:'../action.php',
      columns:{
       identifier:[0, "user_id"],
       editable:[
         [1, 'full_name'], [2, 'username'], [3, 'password']
       , [4, 'mobile_phone'], [5, 'email'], [6, 'role']
       , [7, 'p_a_sejel'], [8, 'p_a_gender'], [9, 'p_a_age_range']
       , [10, 'p_a_family'], [11, 'e'], [12, 'i']
       , [14, 'expiry_date'], [17, 'a']]
      },
      restoreButton:false,
      onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
       if(data.action == 'delete')
       {
        $('#'+data.id).remove();
       }
      }
     });
 
});  
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes, these will collide. Why not use the DataTables editor? https://editor.datatables.net

Comment: You're creating two separate table objects in JS with each script. You need to pick one of these table frameworks and further explore that tool's API.